# Bootstrap: Firefox does not properly place tables above 767px width

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a simple web site with a Bootstrap navbar with tabs. Each tab shows a table. (See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z68mx4qw/).)

This works fine in Chrome 45 and IE 11 on Windows 8.1.

In Firefox however the tables are placed *right* to the navbar if the window width is greater than 767px.

```
<div id="content">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified navbar-header">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Tab 2 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" id="azubiTable">
        <thead>
            <tr id="head">
                <th>1st col</th>
                <th>2nd col</th>
                <th>3rd col</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>3.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>3.2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best interpretation is that this is a float clearing issue not working correctly in FF.

If you add `clear:both` to the div that holds the table it works in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Put `nav` and `table` inside `col-*-12` like this

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified navbar-header">
                    <li class="active"> <a href="#">Tab 1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Tab 2 </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" id="azubiTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="head">
                        <th>1st col</th>
                        <th>2nd col</th>
                        <th>3rd col</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1.1</td>
                        <td>2.1</td>
                        <td>3.1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1.2</td>
                        <td>2.2</td>
                        <td>3.2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z68mx4qw/2/)